# Elementary Group Homomorphisms

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

I am trying to solve the following question:

Let $G$ be a group and $(A, +)$ be an abelian group. For $f,g \in Hom(G,A)$ and $x \in G$ define $(f + g)(x) = f(x) +_A g(x)$.

(a) Show that $f+g \in Hom(G,A)$.

(b) Show that $(Hom(G,A),+)$ is an abelian group.

(c) Let $G$ be a group, and let $id: \ G \rightarrow G$ be the identity homomorphism. Define $f: G \rightarrow G$ by $f(x) = (id(x))(id(x)) = x \cdot x = x^2$. Suppose that $f \in Hom(G,G)$. Show that $G$ is commutative.

In part (a), what does it even mean to say that one adds homomorphisms $f+g$? I understand the idea of adding two functions $f,g \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{R}}$ for instance, since we can add polynomials, but to add homomorphisms makes no sense to me.

Comment: In the second sentence of the problem, it defines what $f+g$ means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's make it clear;

We are not adding homomorphisms ;we are adding functions which satisfy some desired properties i.e $f(x+_Gy)=f(x)+_Af(y)$ where $+_G,+_A$ represent operations in $G,A$ respectively.

For the problem; $(f+g)(x+y)=f(x+y)+g(x+y)$[By definition of $f+g$]=$f(x)+f(y)+g(x)+g(y)=(f+g)(x)+(f+g)(y)$.

Comment: Thank you. That is a clear answer.

Just to make sure, is this sufficient to prove b?

$f,g \in Hom(G,A)$ implies $(f+g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) = g(x) + f(x)$ [because A is abelian) $= (g+f)(x)$.

Comment: yes you are right @letsmakemuffinstogether

Comment: I'm unsure how to begin to solve part (c). Can you recommend a place to start? I am given that there is some $f$ which composes two identity homomorphisms yet I'm not seeing the connection between the existence of such an $f$ and that $G$ is commutative.

Comment: $f(ab)=(ab)^2\implies f(a)f(b)=(ab)^2\implies a.a.b.b=a.b.a.b \forall a,b\in G\implies ab=ba$ .

Comment: Can you please explain how the last implication arrow holds?

Comment: cancellation law

Comment: Oh nice, I see. You just added $a^{-1}$ and $b^{-1}$ to both sides of $a.a.b.b = a.b.a.b.$. Is that right>